# Socket IO client keeps disconnecting / aborting

Tags: python, python-sockets, python-socketio

I'm working on making a simple socket IO quiz bot but it keeps disconnecting and giving an error `packet queue is empty, aborting` and i can't work out why.

The logs:

```
Attempting WebSocket connection to wss://xxxxx.com/socket.io/?transport=websocket&EIO=4
WebSocket connection accepted with {'sid': 'oEzodR82DV63LAfWAAED', 'upgrades': [], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 5000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{}
Received packet MESSAGE data 0
Namespace / is connected
connected!
Emitting event "add user" [/]
Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["add user","Testing"]
Received packet MESSAGE data 2["login",{'userCount': 24}]
Received event "login" [/]
login: {'userCount': 24}
packet queue is empty, aborting
Exiting write loop task
Unexpected error decoding packet: "Invalid empty packet received", aborting
Waiting for write loop task to end
Engine.IO connection dropped
disconnected!
Connection failed, new attempt in 0.50 seconds
Exiting read loop task
```

My Code:

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client(logger=True, engineio_logger=True)


@sio.event
def connect():
  print('connected!')  
  sio.emit('add user', 'Testing')

@sio.on('login')
def login(data):
  print(f'login: {data}')

@sio.event
def connect_error(data):
  print(f'connection error: {data}')

@sio.event
def disconnect():
  print('disconnected!')
  
sio.connect('https://xxxxx.com', transports=['websocket'])
sio.wait()
```

I have tried looking to see if anyone else had similar problem and all i found on it was https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/1077 but looks like they didn't solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Try adding time.sleep(1) in your connect fucntion, before sio.emit('add user', 'Testing')

Comment: I just tried that and i'm still getting the same error. I don't think it has anything to do with the emit `add user` event because the bot joins fine i get the error after like one minute from the bot joining the server.

Comment: Okay, that rules out any synchronization issues. 
This error you are getting is a product of the underlying python-engineio
package. It's triggered when empty payloads are sent. Try checking why empty payloads are send, and try to implement some sort of logic to handle empty packet queues gracefully.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? Logs from the server-side might be useful to troubleshoot this.

Comment: No i don't have any access to the server side.